# summing vector having cells=inf values

Tags: matlab

I need to find out the average of the values

```
Columns 1 through 17

    0.3108    0.7273       Inf    0.2878   -0.0947    0.1286   -0.3108    0.5634    0.2822    0.2362   -0.2628    0.0960   -0.1675   -0.0934   -0.1710   -0.3077   -0.2726

Columns 18 through 20

   -0.0630   -0.5097    0.1823
```

How do I exclude the inf?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To find how many are Inf:

1) find the infs

```
Allvalues{1}<inf                    
ans =
     1     1     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
```

2) Find the number of 0s == Inf

```
sum(~(Allvalues{1}<inf))
ans =
     1
```

Is there another way?

Answer (score 4):

```
>> a=[0.3108    0.7273       Inf    0.2878   -0.0947    0.1286   -0.3108    0.5634    0.2822    0.2362   -0.2628    0.0960   -0.1675   -0.0934   -0.1710   -0.3077   -0.2726 -0.0630 -0.5097 0.1823];
>> mean(a(~isinf(a)))

ans =

    0.0295
```

or `mean(a(a<inf))`.

Comment: thanks to all. Well I am learning new things in here in a very smooth way. Matlabis fun here.                                                               Can I know how many non-Inf values were there? You guys know how to perform tasks in 1 command while i am thinking to do it using a loop thanks

Comment: @pac: I think you may have answered your own question below, but I can't quite tell due to formatting. To get the total number of elements, use `numel(a)` giving (for the example above) `ans = 20`. To get the number of `inf` values (including `-inf`), use `sum(isinf(a))` giving `ans = 1`. To get the number of non-`inf` values, use `sum(~isinf(a))` giving `ans = 19`.